# Sending picture data from Tweet object results in broken image in template

Tags: node.js, express, twitter, pug

I'm trying to send the profile picture data from a Tweet object to my PUG template. However, it keeps resulting in a broken image.

**Snippit from server.js**

```
app.get('/tweet/:id', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await T.get('statuses/show/' + req.params.id, {});    
        res.render('tweet', { stweet_picture: [data.user.profile_image_url_https] });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

**Snippit from PUG template**

```
.tweet-container
            .bird-dude-container
                h3 Information
            .text-container
                h3
                    img(src=`#{stweet_picture}`)
```

Comment: How is it broken? Do you get an error  message?

Comment: No error message. Just the broken image symbol as shown here: https://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_broken_image_00_b_logo_detail.gif